# How to calculate sum for belongsTo model laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get sum of amount for `belongsTo` model on laravel

Here is my code

Controller:

```
$users = AffiliationUser::whereAffiliationId(Auth::user()->id)
    ->with(['user' => function ($q){
        $q->withCount(['billings'])->with(['affiliation_transactions']);
    }])
    ->paginate(3);
//dd($users);
return view('affiliation.users', [
    'users'           => $users,
    'current_balance' => 0,
]);
```

AffiliationUser model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users');
}
```

User model:

```
public function billings() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserBillingSchedules', 'user_id');
}

public function affiliation_transactions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\AffiliationTransaction', 'user_id');
}
```

View:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr class="even pointer">
        <td class="a-center ">{{ $user->user->id }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->user->email }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->user->card_holder }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->user->billings_count  }}</td>
        <td class=" ">{{ $user->user->affiliation_transactions->sum('amount')  }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

It is working good for me, but i don't like idea to get it on view.

```
{{ $user->user->affiliation_transactions->sum('amount')  }}
```

Which one solution i can use also?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the sum with `withCount()`:

```
$users = AffiliationUser::whereAffiliationId(Auth::user()->id)
    ->with(['user' => function ($q) {
        $q->withCount([
            'billings',
            'affiliation_transactions as amount' => function ($q) {
                $q->select(DB::raw('coalesce(sum(amount), 0)'));
            }
        ]);
    }])
    ->paginate(3);

{{ $user->user->amount }}
```

Comment: also did this, working good
but issue with it, if record do not exist i got null instead of some default result
and yes, dont want use '$user->user->amount or 0'  in view
i am new on laravel so want to find best solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Laravel allows you to create custom attributes (using the `get[attributename]Attribute` method in your `Models` easily which can be used to reduce the amount of code you need to write. In this case, you can do this:

**User Model**:

```
public function getTransactionCountAttribute() {
  return $this->affiliation_transactions->sum('amount');
}
```

Now this can be acccessed with the following method in your code:

```
$user->user->transaction_count
```

Also, here's a little more information about [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators), as these are named. Hope they can be useful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

In User Model create a method like:

```
public function sum_amount() {
   return this.affiliation_transactions->sum('amount'); 
}
```

then in your view...

```
{{ $user->user->sum_amount  }}
```